# How to resolve these TypeScript errors when using React refs?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm setting a ref and typing it like this:

```
  const audioElem = useRef<HTMLAudioElement>();
```

Then when I use it like this:

```
  <audio ref={audioElem}></audio>
```

It causes this error:

> (JSX attribute) ClassAttributes.ref?: string |
> ((instance: HTMLAudioElement | null) => void) |
> React.RefObject

And used like this:

```
audioElem.current.style.border = '2px solid red';
```

Causes this error:

> (property) MutableRefObject<HTMLAudioElement | undefined>.current:
> HTMLAudioElement | undefined Object is possibly 'undefined'.

How can I get rid of these errors?

Comment: Consider adding an `if statement` to check if  `current` has a value or put this in a `useEffect`

Comment: what version of typescript are you using? the `current` property can be undefined if the ref was created and used before assigning to an element. While an `if` check would work to make sure `current` is not undefined, a more elegant way to do it is by using [`optional-chaining`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) with version 3.7 and up. That would look something like `audioElem.current?.style.border = '2px solid red';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ref can possibly be `null` in React. Typescript is complaining that you haven't accounted for this possibility.

To resolve the first issue, pass in `null` to `useRef` like this:

```
const audioElem = useRef<HTMLAudioElement>(null);
```

To resolve the second issue, add an `if` statement that checks for `audioElem.current` like this:

```
if(audioElem.current) {
    audioElem.current.style.border = '2px solid red';
}
```

Comment: Just to add more info: this blog has a full explanation of this issue and more "tips" on how to use Typescript with React Hooks: https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react/hooks/#useref